# ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server PROFTPD

Tags: proftpd

I have a problem with my server.
I installed proftpd in my server, and on filezilla its work. But sometime i have this following error

```
ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
```

So, i have to go on my server and restart my proftpd with this following code:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd restart
 * Stopping ftp server proftpd                                           [ OK ]
 * Starting ftp server proftpd                                           [ OK ]
```

Then its work again.

The problem is that i have this error every week so i have to restart each time.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are there any errors in `/var/log/messages` or similar places?

Comment: Also, which version of `proftpd` are you running?

Comment: @Castaglia ProFTPD Version 1.3.5rc3

Comment: I suspect this is caused by [ProFTPD Bug#4044](http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug?id=4044); a `logrotate` configuration (or some other process) might send `SIGHUP` to `proftpd`, triggering this bug.  If you can, I'd recommend removing any `LoadModule mod_facl.c` from your config files.